# How to change clickable image in HTML table row dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two records on an HTML table. In the last column of each row I have an image which is clickable. Upon click, I am calling a JavaScript function.

What I need know is that if the image can be changed once clicked? The changed image should not be clickable and it should not trigger that javascript function.

Please give me a solution for this in jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: post your stuff for getting started..

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `src` attribute of the image clicked to change the image, using [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

You can reference the clicked `img` using `$(this)` in your event handler.

To ensure the new image is not clickable anymore, use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind your event handler.

```
$('img').one('click', function(){
    alert('clicked');
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/50x50');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N34cZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you used jQuery and set clickable like this

```
jQuery('elements').click(function(event){ ... });
```

try to use

```
jQuery('elements').one('click', function(event){ ... });
```